# При копировании массива, добавляются undefined элементы

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, mobx

Работаю с React и MobX. Есть метод в классе для обновления состояния (updateColumns). Когда в переменную состояния (columns) копирую новый массив(newColumns), в нем появляется два undefined элемента. Это происходит даже если я присваиваю переменной значение пустого массива. Все равно в нем два элемента undefined. Есть точно такой же класс с таким же методом, но отвечающий за другие данные. Там все работает нормально и проблем нет никаких. Не могу понять что не так

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

class Columns {
    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    columns = [];

    updateColumns(newColumns) {
        this.columns = newColumns.slice();
    }
}

export default new Columns();
```

Метод вызывается один раз. Консоль лог сразу после присвоения уже показывает наличие двух лишних undefined элементов.

Comment: `console.log("newColumns", JSON.stringify(newColumns)); this.columns = newColumns.slice(); console.log("this.columns", JSON.stringify(this.columns));` - ?

Comment: @Igor, В консоль логах выводится все нормально. А в самом массиве два undefined элемента появляются. Но это если выводить в JSON. Если выводить просто как есть то и в консоли есть undefined

Comment: Когда Вы выводите "просто как есть", консоль запоминает ссылку на объект (массив) и все время показывает его обновленное (текущее) содержимое. Ищите, где Вы что-то добавляете в `columns`.

Comment: @Igor, в том то и проблема, что не добавляю. Даже если я вызываю метод без аргументов и присваиваю column массив вот так: this.columns = [{ column: 1 }], все равно добавляются два undefined

Comment: `this.columns = [{ column: 1 }]; console.log(JSON.stringify(this.columns));` - что показывает в консоли?

Comment: @Igor, показывает: [{"column":1}]

Comment: Очень хорошо. Так в какой момент в массиве появляется дополнительные элементы?

Comment: @Igor, я так понимаю в момент присвоения. Я пишу: this.columns = [{ column: 1 }]. Затем вывожу this.columns в консоль в JSON и как есть. В JSON все нормально, а как есть еще с двумя лишними undefined. Честно я вообще не могу понять как так происходит

Comment: Когда Вы выводите "как есть", консоль запоминает ссылку на объект (массив) и все время показывает его обновленное (текущее) содержимое. Ищите, где Вы что-то добавляете в `columns`.

Comment: @Igor, так. Если, когда я вывожу просто в консоль, то он показывает текущее содержимое. А если я вывожу в JSON то какое это содержимое?

Comment: То это содержимое в момент вызова `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.columns));`, преобразованное в строку. Это значение в консоли уже не изменится, что бы Вы ни делали с `this.columns`.

Comment: @Igor, тогда выходит содержимое `columns` меняется после вызова метода? я просто не могу понять где. я прогонят код через отладчик в браузере. метод больше не вызывается нигде. и еще прошелся поиском по всему проекту чтобы найти вызовы метода. их также нет.

Comment: "содержимое columns меняется после вызова метода" - да. Оно меняется не вызовом методa, а прямыми манипуляциями с `this.columns`.

Comment: @Igor, хорошо. спасибо вам за помощь. теперь хоть знаю что искать.